# CRM 2016-Plugin Registring New Step

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I am very new to MSCRM, so requesting for help. I am using `Office365`, i.e. MSCRM online organisation.
Here, I have written a plugin which should be fired when, in an Account entity, user uploads his image, the plugin stores the image as an attachment, in notes.
The plugin works fine, when I tested it by writing a console application.

I have *registered the plugin* and believe it will work fine here too. The only problem is I am unable to *register the plugin new step*.
The problem is in `Filtering Attributes` , I am unable to get **entityimage** attribute, even if i select/check `All attributes`.
Please suggest how should I proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario you can write plugin on "Create" message of "Annotation" entity. And create message does not have any filtered attributes.

As you wrote and tested using Console Application, while converting it to plugin make sure that you are checking created note contains data into "FileName" and "DocumentBody" attribute. Along with you can also check whether this note is created against "Account" entity. This two conditions will narrow your scope, limited to notes created against account having some attachment. In plugin execution context you'll get above mentioned attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!